# Android's NavigationDrawer without AppCompat

Tags: android, android-support-library, navigation-drawer

I am trying to use the NavigationDrawer within an application that should support Android 4.+

Thus I am using native Activity, ActionBar and Fragment classes (not the support and AppCompat classes).

All seems well except that the navigation drawer icon (the kind-of burger) does not animate to the left when the drawer opens.

Does NavigationDrawer require me to use the AppCompat library and the corresponding support ActionBar stuff?

Comment: So you want to use the DrawerLayout and the ActionBarDrawerToggle without any support library?

Comment: No, just that I don't want to use the fragments and actionbar from support library (just the native ones for now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, NavigationDrawer doesn't require you to user AppCompat staff. Check the listeners they are the most likely cause of your problem, or post your code for us to check.

I am not sure whether the link is correct, but in some of Google I/O 2013 Talk, they recommend to use support library even if you target API 14+ for the simple reason that bug fixes will be faster delivered to you with support library release then with framework release. For this reason I switched our application to use support library components.

P.S. I think it was in this talk http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qlrKh-L4bqU

Comment: My own `ActionBarDrawerToggle#onDrawerSlide` was not calling `super.onDrawerSlide`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `DrawerLayout` for NavigationDrawer, you will have to use support library v4.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html

or perhaps you forgot the `ActionBarDrawerToggle`

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description */
            R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description */
            ) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
        }
    };

    // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns
    // true, then it has handled the app icon touch event
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
      return true;
    }
    // Handle your other action bar items...

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Already got the drawer working with DrawerLayout and all. Only difference is that I am not using the ActionBarCompat stuff (support.v7) but the native stuff.